# Vim/Cygwin: No linebreaks in :! output

Tags: vim, cygwin, xterm

I'm using Vim via MinTTY under Cygwin. When I issue a command like

```
:!ls -la
```

the displayed output doesn't show newlines correctly. It rather just jumps to the virtual column of the next line, where the previous output ended, like this:

```
This is line 1
              This is line 2
                            This line wraps
around
      Line 4 starts here
```

Has anyone an idea, what causes this behaviour? Some settings:

```
:set sh?
sh=/bin/bash

:set shellpipe?
shellpipe=2>&1| tee
```

they were never touched by me. Vim is started with '-X -T xterm-256color', but that doesn't seem to play a role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like it's because of the line-ending differences.  Vim is defaulting to DOS-style CR/LF line endings.  But when you're running the commands, you are seeing only the LF.

I know this doesn't make any sense.

But I'd be interested in seeing what happens if you `:set shellpipe?=2>&1\|unix2dos\|tee` and then `:!ls -la`

Comment: I'm under Linux right now, but I'll test it as soon as I'm back to a Windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen something similar when vim is trying to do smart indenting.  Try using the paste buffer `:!a` because this does not do smart indenting.

Comment: Hm. It seems to be more like a MinTTY+screen+bash issue. I tested under Debian with the same .vimrc and vim version, and everything works fine. On the other hand, even the midnight commander has this strange behaviour, when I issue a `ls -la` there.